# Format Html codes by C# codes programatically ( Like Ctrl + E + D in visual studio )

Tags: c#, visual-studio, knockout.js

I've developed code generator for my framework, which generates html files.

Html files are templates of Knockout, when I run application with unformatted version, knockout makes awful DOM on browser for me.

But when I press Ctrl + E + D to format my generated html in visual studio, and then run app again, I see correct results on UI.

So my question is : how can I format my generated html codes by C# programmatically?

Note: maybe Ctrl + E + D in Visual Studio fixes some common problems too, does anybody know anything about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ctrl+E+D is unbound in my Visual Studio. Ctrl+K+D is bound to "Format Document" - is that the command you mean? (Open Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard and in the "Press Shortcut Keys" textbox, hit Ctrl+E+D - it should then tell you what command those keys are bound to, if you're not sure)

Comment: Ctrl + K + D is format document in Express Edition. In Professional or Ultimate format document is Ctrl + E + D

Comment: @SynerCoder - I'm running Pro and it's Ctrl+K+D for me. I think it may depend on which settings you adopt when you first start VS (I think I normally pick the General Development Settings rather than any language specific one)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I always pick C# environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your generated html file is valid xml you can load the html file in a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and then save it again. [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) will automatically format your xml (html) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/):

> Beautify, unpack or deobfuscate JavaScript and HTML, make JSON/JSONP readable, etc.

Comment: According to my question, I'm not developing html codes by keyboard manually, I'm using a code generator, I'd like to use C# codes to format my generated HTMLs in my code generator. ( As like as first answer )